# Conditionally defining a PHP function using function_exists () and getting an error

Tags: php, function, conditional-statements

I'm using PHP's [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) in [`name spaces`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) to [conditionally](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) define a function.
(PHP 7.4)

In FileA.php I declare and instantiate a function "foo"

```
namespace NSA;
function foo () {};
```

In FileB.php I want to check if the function foo() is available, and if not create function foo() to use.

```
namespace NSB;
use function NSA\foo;
...
# if function foo() does exist create it 
if (!function_exists ('NSA\foo')) {
    # create function foo()
    function foo () {}
}
```

Both files are incorporated in the main program using [`include_once ()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) in the order shown above.

In this scenario `function_exists ('NSA\foo')` returns true as the function does exist.

But I still get the error `Cannot declare function NSB\foo because the name is already in use in FileB.php`

Comment: I would suggest you make yourself familiar with autoloading. PHP-FIG has a great documentation on the recommended PSR4: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. Once you got to this, you will not need such constructs anymore. The example implementation at the end of the page has some great practical advice.

Comment: The statement `use function NSA\foo` sets aside the name `foo` as no longer usable in the current namespace, because if/when used it will be loaded from the source namespace. https://3v4l.org/1nBGJ If you want to import it, you can use an alias. As noted, `function_exists` is rarely needed in modern codebases

Comment: In my context I want to insure the code against the function foo() not being available.
I don't want to write and maintain an autoload function. 
Could you please explain more about using an alias?

Comment: A properly written autoloader has almost no maintenance. I have dozens of libraries and I rarely give them a second thought. But regardless, aliases are in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: the statement ```use function NSA\foo``` is using an alias (it is the equivalent of ```use function NSA\foo as foo```). 
I have read the documentation, including your reference thanks, in advance. I have only asked the question here because the effects of using the statement as described in the documentation was unexpected. I was hoping to minimise duplicated code, not have an autoloader in each of my separate utility functions.